# FTP in iframe on HTTPS page

Tags: http, iframe, https, ftp, ftps

Evening all,

I am having some difficulty with displaying my FTP connection content on a page with HTTPS encryption. It works on standard HTTP but not HTTPS. I am running Apache web server. I'm not fussed about the user being able to see the FTP details just want to secure the connection between both ends though.

Would FTPS on HTTPS work?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ftp:// does work on https websites, although by default its blocked by the "Mixed Content Blocking"

In firefox you can disable this protection by doing what the picture describes:
[image]

For IE:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

ftp:// does not work because of mixed content (e.g. secure https and non-secure ftp).
ftps:// will not work because most browsers do not support it and maybe your ftp server doesn't even speak ftps.

And, how about just testing it before asking, it is not that hard to replace that ftp:// with ftps:// in your page, isn't it?